# How can I convert a list of double array to Bitmap?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, bitmap

I have a list of double array with each array treated as a row in bitmap. I want to convert this list to bitmap. Currently, I have to have 2 steps to do it:

1. Convert List of double array to 2-dimensional double arrays.
2. Convert 2-dimensional double arrays to bitmap.

But the source code consume too much time. Is there any solution to convert directly? Thank you for your support!

```
double[,] bitmap_doublearray = AddedFunction.CreateRectangularArray(data.ListOfRow);
                    Bitmap image_ = AddedFunction.ToBitmap(bitmap_doublearray);

public static T[,] CreateRectangularArray<T>(IList<T[]> arrays)
    {
        int minorLength = arrays[0].Length;
        T[,] ret = new T[arrays.Count, minorLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
        {
            var array = arrays[i];
            if (array.Length != minorLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException
                    ("All arrays must be the same length");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < minorLength; j++)
            {
                ret[i, j] = array[j];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

public static unsafe Bitmap ToBitmap(double[,] rawImage)
    {
        double min_color = Form1.setting_info.GetMinColorValue();
        double max_color = Form1.setting_info.GetMaxColorValue();
        int width = rawImage.GetLength(1);
        int height = rawImage.GetLength(0);

        Bitmap Image = new Bitmap(width, height);
        BitmapData bitmapData = Image.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb
        );
        
        ColorARGB* startingPosition = (ColorARGB*)bitmapData.Scan0;


        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                double color = rawImage[i, j];
                ColorARGB* position = startingPosition + j + i * width;
                int rgb;

                if (color < min_color)
                    color = min_color;
                else if (color > max_color)
                    color = max_color;
                
                rgb = (int)((max_color - color) * 255 / (max_color - min_color));
                
                position->A = 255;
                position->R = (byte)rgb;
                position->G = (byte)rgb;
                position->B = (byte)rgb;
            }

        Image.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        return Image;
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm lost here. How do you get a bitmap from an array of `double`?

Comment: Just convert from element of 2-dimensional double arrays to type of ColorARGB.

Comment: So are you saying that each double is really just 4 bytes (32-bit) of colour in ARGB format that have been stored as a double? Before reading your reply I guessed it might be heightmap information (which would lead to a grayscale image). This is why such information is key to making your question understandable. You should also show your attempt, though if it's only optimisation you seek (and it 100%) works then it's probably better suited to the Code Review Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Firstly, I convert from double element to byte element by specific math. After that, I convert from the elements of a 2-dimensional byte to a type of ColorARGB.

Comment: Actually, I need a new solution to replace my way in current.

Comment: Yes, and you said you have working code that is slow, but you have working code. It is not a question about fixing code, it's a question about optimising it. Code optimisation is more on topic for Code Review.

Comment: I got your point. I have updated a question. Could you review it again?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Bitmap from an array of pixels by copying directly into the Bitmap Scan0 Pointer.
For this you should convert your double array into an RGB or RGBA byte array.
(3-4 bytes per pixel)

```
public static Bitmap CreateFromArray(int w, int h, PixelFormat format, byte[] rgbValues)
{
    var b = new Bitmap(w, h, format);
    var boundsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
    var bmpData = b.LockBits(boundsRect,
                                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                    b.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int bytes = b.Height * Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);

    Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
    b.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    return b;
}
```

If your array contains the whole Bitmap you can recreate a bitmap like this:

```
var bm = Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(byteArr)) as Bitmap;
```

Comment: Thank for you recommendation. I know I can convert from a byte array to bitmap. But the original data of my program is list of array. So I wonder that it consume too much time to execute.

Comment: @CongHoanNguyen I don't think the 'list of array' is the issue; more likely that floating point conversion operations are slowing it down. That `double` type seems weird to me; where does it come from? Can't you receive the original data in a more logical format like `Byte` or `Int32`?

Comment: I can't. Original data is fixed to Double.

Comment: Can you post one of your images raw data as double?